# Array values are being called more than once, how can i limit it so each value is unique?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Hope you can help, my fun project is nearly finished but i have one final bug to fix.

I have an array that shuffles a set of values and then spits them out into random paragraphs. 
The problem is that when i dump these shuffled words some are being called numerous times and i need each value to only print once.

```
$("#generatebutt").click(function() {

var dumpStr = "";
var lengthOfParagraph = $('#length').val();
var numberOfParagraph = $('#numberpara').val();

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParagraph; i++) {
    ShuffleWords(melbArray);

    for (var j = 0; j < lengthOfParagraph; j++) {
        var theWords = melbArray[j];                 
        if(j == 0){
            dumpStr += theWords.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
            theWords = theWords.substring(1)
        }
        else {
        }
        if(j % 5 == 1){
            dumpStr += theWords + ", ";
        }
        else {
            dumpStr += theWords + " ";
        }
    }
    dumpStr = $.trim(dumpStr);
    dumpStr += ".<br/><br/>";
}
$("#dump").html(dumpStr);
```

Thanks so much!

Leigh

Comment: what exactly in ShuffleWords(melbArray); ???

Comment: Do you mean print the values once per paragraph or just once in total? Your inner loop restarts from 0 on each iteration of the outer loop, so `melbArray[j]` will always start over at the beginning when the outer loop increments

Comment: Yes, i want the value to get printed once per paragraph and if it comes up again in the 2nd or 3rd then that's fine. Check out my code on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/GUfFF/84/

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ehqzj/1/

I reckon all you need is a way to grab a unique words from your array and in that case this should help, else can you please flick your HTML as well; Otherwise in case of only getting unique value.

Hope it fits your needs `:)`

**code**

You can use array.filter to do the trick-

```
var a=["hulk","hulk","thor","thor","ironman","hawk","hawk"];

var unique=a.filter(function(itm,i,a){
    return i==a.indexOf(itm);
});

alert(unique);


// Return set will be **Unique** words only: hulk,thor,ironman,hawk
```

Comment: Be careful, the Array methods `filter` and `indexOf` are relatively new, so that older browsers (especially IE < 9) don't support them.

Comment: Hiya @RoToRa thanks, `:)` interesting I thought JQ lib will take care of it, indeed **but** IE is just a funny browser heard it has issues with console.log :P IE 8 I reckon :P anyone with IE? can see how its behaving `B-)` cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

First clone the array (at the beginning of your function) by doing:

```
var newArray = melbArray.slice();
```

Then, using the new array, remove the values from the array when you reference it. Change:

<del>`var theWords = melbArray[j];`</del>

to `var theWords = newArray.splice( j, 1 )[0];`

This `.splice()` method removes the entry at index `j` and returns a new array containing just that (I added the `[0]` to return the element itself). The old array will no longer contain this value after this operation.

Comment: Depending on how your indexing works, you may also have to make some changes to your loop conditions to prevent array-index-out-of-bounds problems

Comment: Works really well but unfortunately i can't use this method because users will want to rerun the function and after a couple of runs there's no values left.

Comment: @user1523498 If that's the only problem with this method you can simply clone it first, as shown in update :)